# Align one set of Vertex to another set of Vertex

Tags: mesh, vertices, snapping

this is my very first question to the group and obviously a new-comer here.  I have been searching for a way to do this but cannot find an answer (i might be asking the wrong questions).  I have two sets of verts (one set has a nice curve and the other is not so nice) and I want to align the "not so nice" verts (on both the X & Y axis, but NOT the Z axis) so both sets of verts are exactly the same (one above the other).  I just cant find a way to do this without manually moving each vert (on X & Y) on the top set to match the lower set.  The attached image shows the difference in the two set (the selected set is the "not so nice" verts that need to align to the non-selected set underneath them).

Is there an easy way to do this in a single command?  I did try snapping but I could only get it to snap on all three axis which was not the outcome I wanted.

Cheers and thanks in advance,
VTB...

[image]

Comment: it would probably be faster to duplicate the good edge loop

Answer (score 0):

Duplicating the ideal part would the best and fastest way as @moonboots suggests.

Having two seperate objects (Separate > by selection) you could use the **shrinkwrap modifier** with *Wrap Method: Nearest Vertex*. Afterwards you could apply the modifier and join your objects back together.
[image]

Comment: Awesomeness!  Thanks for quick and very helpful response.  I'm slowly learning these modifiers as I go (and there's a lot!).  So, I just learnt about a new one!  Not only do I need to duplicate that ark of verts, but once I get that right, I need to duplicate the whole leg that it sits on out to the other 3 legs.  This should do the trick.

Cheers and thanks once again,
VTB